# Constraint array of integers to be within certain range

Tags: arrays, for-loop, constraints, system-verilog-assertions

All,

I'm trying to come up with a SystemVerilog constraint which will for e.g. `byte my_array [0:8]` loop through all the elements in the array to restrict their values to be within the range from 1 to 9. Something like:

```
restrict: assume property (
    foreach(my_array[i]) my_array[i] inside {[1:9]}
);
```

The above is not accepted by the parser. Please help! I can generate 9 constraints within a loop, but would like to have something more elegant. So, below is a current workaround.

```
genvar i;
 for (i=0; i<=8; i++) begin : legal_nums
  restrict: assume property (
   my_array[i] inside {[1:9]}
 ); 
end : c
```

Thanks!

Comment: Are you trying to write a constraint or a property? A cover property will check if your randomly-generated `my_array` elements are inside `[1:9]` in simulation. A constraint will actually constrain your randomly-generated `my_array` elements to be inside `[1:9]`. Which one do you need?

Comment: I made a type while posting the question. It should be a constraint.

Comment: This isn't a systemverilog random constraint. It is an assume property. Are you writing properties for formal verification?

Comment: Yes, of course. I never wrote it is a random constraint :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are writing properties, you need to use the `generate` statement. I did this a while ago and after much research, this was the only way possible.